# Which axis is used for the near and far plane when using the perspective camera?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created an example project and read a great [tutorial](https://discoverthreejs.com/book/first-steps/first-scene/) on three.js but one thing is not described well when creating the perpsective camera.

When an object is created an added into the scene for a default location of (0,0,0) and the camera is set and moved back 10 units to make the object easily visible, I have specified a near and far plane of `0.1` and `1000`. I am not sure which axis this is specified on, however whichever axis it is specified on, none of the axis's on the default object are `>=` `0.1` to be visible given that the near and far planes specify that the visible objects must be between these planes.

Could someone please explain why my object is visible in the scene, which axis the near and far plane are or provide a very useful link describing it as I cannot find a link to explain well.

Code below if interested.

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import 'bootstrap';
import css from '../css/custom_css.css';

let scene = new THREE.Scene();

/* Constants */
let WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
let HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

/* Camera */
let field_of_view = 75;
let aspect_ratio = WIDTH/HEIGHT;
let near_plane = 0.1;
let far_plane = 1000;
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(field_of_view, aspect_ratio, near_plane, far_plane);
// every object is initially created at ( 0, 0, 0 )
// we'll move the camera back a bit so that we can view the scene
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 10 );

/* Renderer */
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true, canvas: my_canvas });
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
renderer.setClearColor(0xE8E2DD, 1);

// Create the shape
let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
// Create a material, colour or image texture
let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
    color: 0xFF0000,
    wireframe: true
});

// Cube
let cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

// Game Logic
let update = function(){
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.005;
};

// Draw Scene
let render = function(){
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

// Run game loop, update, render, repeat
let gameLoop = function(){
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);

    update();
    render();
};

gameLoop();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The near and far planes for a perspective camera are relative to the camera itself, they are not on one of the global scene axes.

In your case, the near plane is a plane `0.1` units away from the camera along the camera's central axis or "look" vector, and the far plane is a plane `1000` units away. Things rendered must be between these two planes inside the camera's "view frustum".

So in your example, since the camera is looking at the object and the object is `10` units away, it's within the view frustum and is therefore visible.

See this youtube video for a more visual representation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyTaxN2XUyQ
[image]